# Installing MPI for Windows

Tags: mpi, windows-8.1

I am trying to install MPI for Windows 8, so when I searched net I got steps for installing it on XP/7 but not for windows 8. The link is: http://swash.sourceforge.net/online_doc/swashimp/node9.html

But firstly when I have to allow mpi.exe and smpd.exe to communicate through firewall these exe files are not listed.
Secondly, when I run cmd(as administrator) and type : "smpd -install", 
it says : "Unknown option: -install". I  guess the command for windows 8 is something else.
So I will be really grateful if anyone helps with it because I'm not able to proceed further.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Apparently, MS-MPI does not support these options. Did you find a solution to the problem, e.g. a good resource on how to start with MS-MPI?

Comment: MS-MPI is, in fact, MPICH for Windows.

Answer (score 28):

Side note before I start, [MPI](http://www.mpi-forum.org) is a standard, not a library that you install. [MPICH](http://mpich.org), [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org), [Intel MPI](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mpi-library), [MS-MPI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467), etc. are all implementations of that standard. When you say you're trying to do X with MPI and you're asking for help, mention which implementation (and version) you're using.

Based on your question, I'm assuming that you're trying to install MPICH, though which version is unclear. MPICH hasn't supported Windows since version 1.4.1p and even that version doesn't have any support from the MPICH team anymore as all of the Windows experts are now gone. I'd suggest that you take a look at one of the implementations that do currently support Windows. The only two I know of are [MS-MPI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467) (free) and [Intel MPI](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mpi-library) (paid - Update: Now free for most users), though there are probably others out there that I don't know about. If you still have trouble after trying one of those implementations, they have their own support teams that can help you with your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for my question not being clear. I'm trying to install MS-MPI now can u tell the possible solution?

Comment: Not really. I know very little about MS-MPI. You're probably going to need to go through their official support channel if you need help. I've never seen anyone here who has answered MS-MPI questions, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of MSMPI you were talking about but here is the [webpage](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44990) you should download the latest MSMPI which also supports Win 8.1.

You just need to double click and follow the instructions of installer.