# Installing Open-MPI on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to install Open MPI for Windows 8.1 and when I searched for it I got instructions for installing it on Windows XP & 7, but not for Windows 8.1.

A question like this was asked in stackoverflow a year ago: [Installing MPI for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153750/installing-mpi-for-windows), but the question was not clear so it did not got any answers.

I also installed [MS-MPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx), but when I want to compile a simple cC++ file, Visual Studio 2013 doesn't recognize `#include < mpi.h >`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Installing on Windows 8.1 should be not much different than installing on Windows 7. For MS MPI, you should add the path to the library header files and the path to the import library in the project settings.

Comment: how should i add this path?
where to add it, what exactly i should add?

Comment: You might be able to find an MS-MPI user who can help you here, but I haven't seen any so far. You might have better luck on the MS-MPI forums: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowshpcmpi. On a related note, I'm pretty sure the Open MPI doesn't support Windows and hasn't for a long time.

Comment: Thank you for editing, If the Open MPI doesnt support Windows then what is MS-MPI for?

Comment: MS-MPI  and intel mpi provide supported windows-based implementations of MPI.

Comment: Each is a different implementation of the MPI Standard. They don't depend on each other and most of the time having multiple installations will conflict and cause problems if you're not careful.

Comment: Open MPI 1.6 was the last Open MPI branch supported on Windows. Their Windows maintainer left some time ago and thereafter the newer versions are only supported on Unix-like systems.

Comment: You should do something like this: 
First you have to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 , Then you should download : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36044 .  and install it , Then download : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44990 . and install if after Hpc Client.
Then you should add a system variable with name : "anything" , and path: "Bin folder of directory that yo installed Hpc like 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin ' ".