# Cmake error: could not find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND)

Tags: cmake, mpi

I'm trying to install a software called relion on a windows pc, but am running into some issues. I try to build relion with <cmake .. -G 'Visual Studio 16 2019'> to set my C compiler, and I am not able to find MPI

Answer (score 0):

MPI, a standard, has several implementations.  See this old but good answer covering the options you've got (MS-MPI or Intel-MPI )

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165460/1024740